# Change image src of imagebutton using jquery 1.4.4

Tags: jquery, background-image, imagebutton

I tried to change the image src of **ImageButton** using jQuery then it fails to change the background.

I have tried below script or that:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
 {
    $('#<%=imageButtonId.ClientID%>').click(function () 
    {

            $('#<%=imageButtonId.ClientID%>').attr("src", "mobile/images/writelogbook_icon.png");

     });
});
```

I have also tried object.css("backgroundImage","path");
But, this also fails.
Please suggest me. I am using jquery 1.4.4 min

**Edit:**
Relavent code from html:

```
<input type="image" name="imageButtonId" id="imageButtonId" src="Images/admin.png" />



   $('#imageButtonId).click(function () {
$(this).attr('background-image', 'Images/customer.png');        });
```

Thanks,

Naresh Goradara

Comment: What is not working, the click event or the `attr()` call?

Comment: your second effort should be `object.css("background-image","path");` (with a dash and lowercase `i`)

Comment: Event is fired but no change in output.

Comment: @Dutchie432:  background-image also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imageButtonId" runat="server" src="Images/admin.png"> 
</asp:ImageButton>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=imageButtonId.ClientID%>').click(function (e) {

            $('#<%=imageButtonId.ClientID%>').attr("src", "Images/customer.png");
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works fine in my test-project. Just remember the e.preventDefault, and also passing in e in the click-function. This causes the Image-button to not post back to the server, hence refreshing the page.

If the page refreshes, the imagebutton will have its original image again.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine but as you told it replace original image when page refresh. It that any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: you'll need to set the image source in code behind on Page_Load or the click-event for the imagebutton if you want the picture to persist.

Please mark the answer as accepted aswell.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell from your question. A few things to try:

1. Look at your HTML source on the generated page. What is `<%=imageButtonId.ClientID%>` rendered as?
2. Alert `$('#<%=imageButtonId.ClientID%>').length`. What do you get?
3. Personally, I wouldn't have the second `$('#<%=imageButtonId.ClientID%>')`. Use `$(this)` instead.

You could try posting some of the rendered page (i.e. the HTML with imageButtonId and the rendered JavaScript. This will help us determine what is wrong.

Comment: object.ClientId, i got object of imagebutton, with length of 1. ANd using this is considered it as simple DOM object, which doesn't suppport jQuery methiods.

Comment: @Naresh - Can you post the *relevant* code from the rendered html page.

Comment: I have added relavent html on question, please have a look and suggest.

Comment: @Naresh: Post the rendered Javascript as well. Then go and accept some of the answers to your other questions, and vote up any answers you found useful.

Answer (score 1):

What html type is #imageButtonId.ClientID?  The src is used with images, not buttons (just in case you're trying this with a button).  If it's a button, you must use css('background-image', path).  Note the background-image - NOT camelCase.

If that still doesn't work, check the object's CSS in some dev tool like firebug, safari / chrome's developer tools, etc.  Is the property changing, just not showing the image, or is nothing being set.

And like was said before, you want to use $(this).css('background-image', path);

Good luck!

Edit:
Just noticed your html addition - why not just do:

```
$('#imageButtonID').click(function() {
   $(this).css('background-image', 'path/to/image');
});
```

Also unless you require the image map type functionality of type=image, I'd recommend using a styled button instead.  You'd just style it with css (inline like style='background-image:path/to/image.png' or in a style sheet.  Like:

```
<input name='imageButtonID' id='imageButtonID' style='background-image:path/to/image.png'>
```

Then

```
$('#imageButtonID').click(function() {
   $(this).css('background-image', 'path/to/newimage.png');
});
```

Comment: I can not replace asp ImageButton into html simple button with style.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative path.  Is the path to your image correct?  Try using an absolute path.

Comment: Image path is also correct, if I use same path by simple javascript then it works fine.